# Aging Bucket DAX formula issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

I have a table as stated below,

```
MEM_ID  dateDiff
4522       10
111         1
1112       -1
1232        5
121135     20
145        30
12254      60
```

I want a Dax formula which will give the output as stated below under measure column as

```
MEM_ID  dateDiff      Measure
4522       10         0-15 Days
111        1          0-15 Days
1112      -1           <0 Days
1232       5          0-15 Days
121135    20          15-30 Days
145       30          15-30 Days
12254     60           >60 Days
```

I have used this formula which didnt worked, any help much appriricated =IF(MAX([DateDiff]) <= 1, "0", IF(MAX([DateDiff])>=1 && MAX([DateDiff])<15,"1-15 Days",IF(MAX([DateDiff])>=15 && MAX([DateDiff])<30,"15-30 Days",IF(MAX([DateDiff])>=30 && MAX([DateDiff])<60,"30-60 Days",IF(MAX([DateDiff])>=60 && MAX([DateDiff])<90,"60-90",BLANK())))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a lookup-table like Ian Ash suggests is better, but if you must use an IF formula, Try the formula you have, but delete the MAX functions.

```
=IF([DateDiff]< 1, "0",
 IF([DateDiff]>=1 && [DateDiff]<15,"1- 15 days", 
 IF([DateDiff]>=15 && [DateDiff]<30,"15-30 Days",
 IF([DateDiff]>=30 && [DateDiff]<60,"30-60 Days",
 IF([DateDiff]>=60 && [DateDiff]<90,"60-90",
 BLANK())))))
```

Comment: I have found a solution with this formula =SWITCH(TRUE(),LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<0 &&LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=-1,"Negative",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>1 &&LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<15,"1-15",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>=15 &&LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=30,"15-30",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>30 && LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=60,"30-60",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>60,"More than 60 Days")

Comment: @marcos Vos Thanks alot brother for helping

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by creating a look up table as follows.

Create a new worksheet called `Lookup`, then starting from `A1` add the following data:

```
Min      Max    Bucket       Description
-1000     0            1         <0 Days
1        15            2         0 - 15 Days
16       30            3         16 - 30 Days
```

You can add additional rows if you need to add more buckets. For example, to create a bucket for 30 to 60, you would add the row:

```
31       60            4         30 - 60 Days
```

Once you have the lookup table defined, you can reference into it using the following formula from your main worksheet:

```
=OFFSET(Lookup!$A$1,SUMPRODUCT((B2>=Lookup!$A$2:$A$4)*(B2<=Lookup!$B$2:$B$4)*(Lookup!$C$2:$C$4)),3)
```

In the above formula, the value being looked up is in `B2`.

If you have added rows to your lookup table, you will need to extend the look up range in the formula, i.e. `Lookup!$A$2:$A$4` changes to `Lookup!$A$2:$A$5` and so on.

Comment: Thanks mate, i will give it a go, but before that do you think we can achieve it with IF formula?

Comment: Sure, as per the answer you've accepted. My personal view is that nested IFs are error prone and hard to maintain when changes are required, but of course they work.

Comment: As i had to take text value along with int i used the below formula, =SWITCH(TRUE(),LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=0 &&LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=-1,"Negative Days",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>=1 &&LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<15,"1-15 Days",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>=15 &&LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=30,"15-30 Days",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>30 && LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]<=60,"30-60 Days",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]>60,"More than 60 Days",LM_Conversion_range[DateDiff]=0,"Same Day") Thanks alot brother for your kind help.